# Cement Bag project help

Tags: modeling

i am new at this Blender things. If i want to create a cement bag like this, then make it falls down onto the ground. Any tutorial for me for this project? Actualy i made a cube with cloth simutation and it almost there, but it keeps falling through the plane :(
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDK8ymyBv0pFvh8cKgRb0gPMmtROQGhy/view?usp=sharing
[image: bag]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to remove the Rigid body physics from the . There is no need for those for the cloth simulation to work. Remove them and the cloth simulation will start working properly.

You can keep the rigid body physics on the on the plane if you are planning to use other rigid body objects. But the cloth doesn't need it.

Some extra tips: As of right now the collision plane has too much outer thickness in the collision properties. Reduce it to reduce the distance between the cloth and the plane.

Comment: i added the collision modifer to my plane but cannot fix my problem. do i have to change anything in the Collision tab?

Comment: In that case please share your file. There can be some other reason as to why that's happening. Use blend exchange. Follow the instructions on the site and paste the link into the question by editing. Also provide the details that you added the modifier but it still doesn't work in the question itself.

Comment: i dunno how to add file directly in this site, so i add a google drive link to my file, tks for helping

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out